# Ising model: typical values of $J$

Tags: ising-model

In a typical (simple, 1D) Ising model, we have

$$\mathcal{H}=-\frac{J}{2} \sum_{\langle i, j\rangle} \sigma_{i} \sigma_{j}-B \sum_{i} \sigma_{i}, \quad \sigma_{i}=\pm 1$$

However, what is the typical value of $J$ that can be used in an experiment?

Comment: Hint: would a value of $J$ (in the absence of a value for $B$) actually tell you anything? What if you scaled both constants by the same factor?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty In an experiment (with real materials), J sets the energy scale - so it e.g. tells you at what temperature to expect a phase transition.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty it wouldn't, I think, and scaling doesn't alter the main physics. I mean that is the same thing as the absolute value of the energy does not say anything, only the difference in energies has a physical meaning. (of course, this is argument invalidated by E=mc^2, but we are not doing anything relativistic, so we can get away with not setting our zero-energy state).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I got it, but can you give a real, actual value that was used in any actual experiment

Comment: Comment wasn't addressed to you. In any case, I'm not an expert on materials, but I think a classical Ising 1D model is not very common in real materials.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You are of course correct. On the other hand, there are systems reasonably well approximated by a *2d* Ising model (actually, remarkably well). One can find a review [here](https://doi.org/10.1590/S0103-97332000000400030). Of course, the Ising model is important irrespective of whether it describes quantitatively any specific system. Nevertheless, these examples might provide one possible answer to the OP.

Comment: @Yvan Didn't mean to say the Ising model is not important! But to get actual coupling constants, you need actual realizations (either in a material or some quantum simulator).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Sorry, I must have been unclear: I am in complete agreement with you :) . I just wanted to point out to the OP that the point of the Ising model is not its ability to describe quantitatively any specific material (even though there are some which it, maybe accidentally, describes well). I should have written 2 separate comments, that would have been less confusing ;) .